# Any cursorLoader with out content provider that notyfies data change?

Tags: android

i am working on a project where i have recyclerview and i populate the recyclerview with data from database and i am using cursor loader to load the data and custom cursor adapter to set the data to recyclerview.I have not created any content provider because my app dose not share any information.But the problem is since i am not using any content provider cursorloader is not refreshing after the data change.I just want to know if there is any way to solve the problem or are there any custom cursorloaders that do the work..
***Thank you***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can use content providers without sharing the contents with other apps. Honestly I don't know why the documentation states that you only should use one if you want to share data. Thats nonsense considering that you get tons of neat features for free by simply using a content provider. And if you don't want to share any data with other apps, then set the 'exported' flag to false in the manifest file.

If you don't want to use a provider, then you can signal a change with:

[any Context].getContentResolver().notifyChange(youtUri, null)

Comment: Thanks man lot of people suggested to create a content provider..so i created a content provider